# How to use gesture and select buttons in that gesture

Tags: ios, swift

Hello I am making an app with 64 button(8x8) and I would like to use an gesture so when the player taps one of the buttons and then slides into other buttons, all of them are (tapped)

So whenever you slide though those buttons, all of those buttons in the slide are getting tapped

Does anyone have an option to this?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you explain more..

Comment: Do you need them to be buttons? Or could they be labels or plain views?

Comment: I already have the buttons. I edited the post.

Comment: Show the code you have written to try to solve this. People won’t write it for you.

Comment: @LesleyHutchinson - *"I already have the buttons"* does not answer the question... do they ***need to be buttons***? Or can they just be squares / rectangles?

Comment: I really don't know where to start

Comment: @DonMag They don't need to be buttons, but it needs a letter in each square

Answer (score 1):

See if this will get you going.

We create a 8x8 grid of labels. I used the "row"-"column" number for the text of each label. You can replace that with whatever text you want displayed (such as letters).

Then we use `touchesBegan` and `touchesMoved` to track the touch movement, changing the background color of each "tile" that is touched as the user drags a finger around the grid:

```
class MultiSelectViewController: UIViewController {

    var tilesArray: [UIView] = [UIView]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var x: CGFloat = 30
        var y: CGFloat = 40
        let w: CGFloat = 40

        for row in 1...8 {
            for col in 1...8 {
                let v = UILabel()
                v.backgroundColor = .blue
                v.text = "\(row)-\(col)"
                v.textAlignment = .center
                v.textColor = .white
                v.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10, weight: .light)
                v.layer.borderColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
                v.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
                v.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: w, height: w)
                tilesArray.append(v)
                view.addSubview(v)
                x += w
            }
            y += w
            x = 30
        }

    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)

        if let t = touches.first {
            let loc = t.location(in: self.view)
            for v in tilesArray {
                if v.frame.contains(loc) {
                    v.backgroundColor = .red
                    break
                }
            }
        }

    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)

        if let t = touches.first {
            let loc = t.location(in: self.view)
            for v in tilesArray {
                if v.frame.contains(loc) {
                    v.backgroundColor = .red
                    break
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Here is how it looks (after dragging a bit):

[image]

---

**Edit**

How to restrict dragging to a straight line? There could be many different approaches, but here's a general idea...

Suppose we first select tile `3-3`:

[image]

There are 7 tiles we could drag to next, so we keep track of those tile locations. That could be done with math, an array of points, an array of index values, an array of tile objects, etc.

Let's make an array, and call it `selectableTiles`.

Note that if we start at an edge (or corner) we won't have all 7 positions available, so that has to be taken into account:

[image]

As we drag, find the "current" tile at the touch point and see if it's in our `selectableTiles` array. If it is, we select that tile also. Once we have two tiles selected, there can be only one tile available. In this case, tile `1-1`:

[image]

The first time we try it, though, we'll see it's almost impossible to drag on a diagonal without crossing an adjacent tile. So, we need to keep the original `selectableTiles` available:

[image]

If we continue to drag within the original `selectableTiles`, we de-select and keep updating the one-and-only next selectable tile:

[image]

Once we have moved to a third tile, we can get rid of our original `selectableTiles` and we only need to track the new one-and-only next selectable tile:

[image]

When we reach the edge, we're done:

[image]

Comment: But is there a way to clip it to 45 degrees like when you start at 1-1 you can go straight down, to the right or oblique to 2-2?

Comment: @LesleyHutchinson - **of course** there is a way to do that. But... this answers the question in your post: *"So whenever you slide though those buttons, all of those buttons in the slide are getting tapped"* The next part is up to you. If you cannot get it to work, then come back and ask a ***new*** question. But... you need to put in some work first.

Comment: Can you please help me @DonMag, I can't find how... And I am really dedicated to this app.

Comment: @LesleyHutchinson - *"I am really dedicated to this app"* ... Is this for a school assignment? Or for an app you want to distribute (sell?) via the App Store? Have you tried to work out the logic of doing what you want?

Comment: I tried and have been looking for hours and still no progress. Please help me with this. I can't post another question on stack overflow neither

Comment: @LesleyHutchinson - I can give you more help, but let me ask you again (since you didn't answer): ***Is this for a school assignment? Or for an app you want to distribute (sell?) via the App Store?***

Comment: I want to distribute it via the App Store

Comment: @LesleyHutchinson - See the **Edit** to my answer. I've described one approach to restricting dragging to in-line tiles.

Comment: @LesleyHutchinson - *I want to distribute it via the App Store* -- OK... please take the Stack Overflow [tour]. This is not a "do my work for me" site. Perhaps you should look into hiring a developer?